# How to click on a button using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am unable to click on the "Get Details button".

the HTML Tag is mentioned below

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Get Details</button>
```

Code:

```
Sub chromAuto()

    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    obj.Start "chrome"
    obj.Get "websitedetails"
    obj.FindElementById("asin").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Can you share the actual url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how many items there are with this class. A faster method would be to use css selectors e.g.

With selenium

```
obj.FindElementByCss(".btn-success").click
```

More than one element index into the nodeList

```
obj.FindElementsByCss(".btn-success")(1).click '1 is an example index
```

With ie and Microsoft Internet Controls

```
ie.document.querySelector(".btn-success").click
```

Comment: how will it be with chrome since i am using chrome.

Comment: Use the top version is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about the HTML environment, but you could try the following:

```
Dim ie_obj As Object
Set ie_obj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie_obj.Visible = True

ie_obj.Navigate "www.somesite.com"

Do While ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("my_name")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).click
```

Comment: Sub chromAuto()

    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    obj.Start "chrome", ""
    obj.Get "websitedetails"

    obj.FindElementById("asin").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value)

Comment: Did you try out the last command from my answer? I did it once that way. I am not sure how it would behave with `SendKeys(...)`. And what is stored in cell "A2" in your first sheet?

Comment: so the macro picks ups values from a excel sheet and fills in the website. A2 is the cell name in which the first value is present. till where i have made the macro its putting all the information in teh correct place on the website but it does not click on the "Get Details" part. i wanted help on that. the command does not work which you shared